# Saving/duplicating a file pointer/descriptor

Tags: c, file, dup, file-pointer

I have a requirement where in there is a **global** `FILE` pointer/descriptor. One of the functions will read from this pointer/descriptor. The ***internal pointer*** associated with the `FILE` pointer/descriptor advances. After this function returns, ***I want to read from the same `FILE` pointer/descriptor and also the same data as the other function read.***

But I cant read the same exact data, as the internal pointer has advanced. *Duplicating the descriptor doesn't work* as the duplicate mirrors the original. Saving the `FILE` pointer before read also doesn't work as it is a pointer and will again start referring to the same thing.

One alternative is to save the file position using `fgetpos()` before read and use `fsetpos()` before the next read.

But this works for file pointers and not descriptors.

With normal pointers its so easy. But things get difficult with `FILE` pointers.

Are there any other *non-clumsy* methods of achieving this?

Comment: `man lseek` for file descriptors

Comment: Why do you want to read the data twice?  Doing so is clumsy, and any method to do it will be inherently clumsy.

Comment: @WilliamPursell The scenario is that I've to log the data for debugging and as well as utilize it for some other purpose.

Comment: So why do you need to read it twice?  You need to use it twice, but you don't need to read it twice.

Comment: @WilliamPursell As its a global pointer, the point of logging and the point of utilization are way way apart. So, storing the read data and letting others read from there is again very clumsy

Comment: Linux-specific hack: you can `dup` a file descriptor without sharing flags and offset by opening the files in `/dev/fd`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to POSIX file descriptors, it sounds like you're looking for `lseek()`.

```
off_t off;

off = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR); /* get current offset */
/* do some read(s) */
lseek(fd, off, SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: Right. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question -- I thought the point was to seek back so the same data could be read again. In that case I'm not sure why (or even if) there is a `dup()`'ed fd at all.

Answer (score 0):

another option would be to memory-map the file using [`mmap()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap).

This will allow you to randomly read any position within the file without having to use `lseek()` or `fseek()`.

you'll find a short tutorial on `mmap()` at [linuxquestions](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/mmap-tutorial-c-c-511265/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I would hide that file pointer behind another interface that buffers the last-read chunk of data, so that different areas of the code can access the same data without having to rewind the stream.